# Any opinions on Schoof's "Catalan's Conjecture"?

Tags: book-recommendation

Title basically says it all: I'm wondering if anyone has used this book and what their opinion was.  Specifically I'd like to make sure the book is approachable but also complete.  Background on me to check for compatibility on the "approachable" criterion:

I'm a recently finished undergrad who is taking some time off before grad school and I'd love to understand the proof of Catalan's Conjecture/Mihailescu's Theorem.  I have a solid background in Abstract Algebra and some background in Galois Theory and Algebraic Number Theory (took a class on GT that went through the impossibility of solving the general quinitc with radicals and the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, and I've self-studied Stewart and Tall's [Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat's Last Theorem](https://www.crcpress.com/Algebraic-Number-Theory-and-Fermats-Last-Theorem-Fourth-Edition/Stewart-Tall/p/book/9781498738392) and Jarvis's [Algebraic Number Theory](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319075440)).

Also, if anyone else has recommendations for a good self-contained proof of the theorem, or other subjects that I should study before attempting to read any such proof, please let me know!

Thanks for any help.